# Confused about notation for partial derivatives, like $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(y, g(x))$

Tags: notation, partial-derivative

I have recently started reading applied-sciences papers and am getting extremely confused about notation when considering function composition and partial derivatives.

For example, say we have a function $f$ that maps $x \in \mathbb R$, $y \in \mathbb R$ to $f(x,y) \in \mathbb R$. Say we also have a function $g$ that maps $z \in \mathbb R$ to $g(z) \in \mathbb R$, and now define $h(x,z) = f(x,g(z))$.

Chain rule yields $\frac{\partial h}{\partial z} (x,z) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,g(z))$  $\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}(z)$, which is fine. But papers in this field typically go for $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} f(x,g(z)) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,g(z)) \frac{\partial}{\partial z} g(z)$, without ever defining the composition $h$ in the first place. This can be especially confusing if one overloads $y$, yielding $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,g(y)) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,g(y)) \frac{\partial}{\partial y} g(y)$ which simply doesn't make sense to me.

I know defining a new function every time we consider a composition can be cumbersome, but I don't see how the above is acceptable in papers that appear in academic journals. Am I missing something here? If the above is indeed confusing, then what would be a good notation standard to adopt instead of defining new functions for each composition?

Here is an example from a published paper:

[image]

[image]

My question is: is this notation ambiguous? When writing my own research papers, should I define new functions for each composition, or is the notation above acceptable?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Is the notation I described (like $\frac{\partial}{\partial_z} f(x,g(z))$ correct, as in is it not ambiguous? Some papers also use $\frac{\partial f(x,g(z))}{\partial_z}$, which rigorously would be zero since $f(x,g(z))$ is just a scalar.

Comment: $L_1$ is not defined so its hard to say from that alone.It is common practice to use ambiguous language/notation in formal mathematical papers as it is understood that the reader will have sufficient mathematical maturity to "fill in the blanks" from the context. For instance, $gcd(a,b)$ is frequently just denoted by $(a,b)$.

Comment: In this specific case, $L_1$ is just said to be $L_1 : \phi \mapsto L(\phi) \in \mathbb R$ (note that its definition has no dependence on $\phi_0$ or $\phi_1$!). I assume that $L_1(\phi_1)$ actually denotes a function $\overline L(\phi_0) = L_1(\phi_1(\phi_0))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, shortcuts are necessary, and some of them are perfectly acceptable. One of those shortcuts is to remove the explicit dependency on the variables, i.e. to write $g$ instead of $g(y)$ in your example. Thus, one could write
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial y} f(x,g) = \frac{\partial }{\partial g} f(x,g)\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}
$$
according to the chain rule. This is possible if the reader was told that $g$ is a function of $y$, and that $x$ doesn't depend on $y$. Even shorter
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g} \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\, ,
$$
and still perfectly acceptable, provided that $f$ was defined as a function of $x$ and $g$.